# Share a "deep link" from a Windows 8/WinRT application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, deep-linking

I have searched using many different terms and phrases, and waded through many pages of results, but I have (remarkably) not seen anyone else addressing, even asking, about, this issue. So here goes...

**Ultimate Goal:** Allow a user viewing a content-based page (may contain both text and images) within a Windows Store app to share that content with someone else.

**Description**
I am working on taking a fair amount of content and making it available for browsing/navigating as a Windows 8/WinRT/Windows Store (we need a consistent name here) application. One of the desired features is to take advantage of the Share Charm, such that someone viewing a page could share that page with someone else.

The ideal behavior is for the application to implement the Share Source contract which would share an email message that contained some explanatory text, a link to get the app from the Windows Store, and a "deep link" into the shared page in the application.

**Solutions Considered**
We had originally looked at just generating a PDF representation of the page, but there are very few external libraries that would work under WinRT, and having to include externally licensed code would be problematic as well. Writing our own PDF generation code would out of scope.

We have also considered generating a Word document or PowerPoint slide using OpenXML, but again, we run up against the limitaions of WinRT. In this case, it is highly unlikely the OpenXML SDK is useable in a WinRT application.

Another thought was to pre-generate all of the pages as .pdf files, store them as resources, and when the Share Charm is invoked, share the .pdf file associated with the current page. The problem here is the application will have at least 150 content pages, and depending on how we break the content down, up to over 600. This would likely cause serious bloat.

**Where We Are At**
Thus we have come to sharing URIs. From what I can tell, though, the "deep linking" feature is only intended for use on Secondary Tiles tied to your application. Another avenue I considered was registering a protocol like, "my-special-app:" with the OS and having it fire up the application but that would require HKCR registry access, which is outside the WinRT sandbox.

If it matters, we are leaning towards an HTML/JS application, rather than XAML/C#, because the converted content will all be in HTML and the WebView control in WinRT is fairly limited. This decision is not yet final, though.

**Conclusion**
So, is this possible, and if so, how would it be done or where can I find documentation on it?

Thanks,
Dave Parker

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, you want to allow people to share content to other people who may not have the application installed? Is it undesirable to require people to have the application installed prior to receiving the share link?

Comment: @justin-skiles I am not sure what you are getting at. Assuming we make the assumption that the share recipeint has the application installed prior to receiving the share link, is there a way to structure the link to open the application and navigate to that page?

Comment: A Windows Store app can register a protocol handler: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec

Comment: @NathanKuchta. That appears to be the answer I am looking for. However, I cannot mark a comment as the answer, so if you can make your answer and actual answer, I will mark it as such and people can vote on it accordingly. Thank you very much.